# Preventing a MEX file from crashing in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, crash, mex

I have a MEX file which I "borrowed" from someone else to help me code a semi-automated nuclear detection algorithm. The problem is that the MEX file sporadically causes a segmentation fault.  However, if the code is run with the same parameters a second time, it's fine.

I was hoping there was a sort of `try/catch` idiom for MEX files, but after spending most of my Saturday looking for something, I couldn't find anything.

Any help on this issue would be amazing! Otherwise, I am going to have to port the `.cpp` into MATLAB (and it's around 10,000 lines using hundreds of dependencies :-().

Comment: And you don't want any code crashing with nuclear related codes. It could start wars!

Comment: Instead of causing a segment fault, invalid Code may also modify random memory addresses of your Matlab process, accepting errors you can not reliably detect is a bad idea!

Comment: You really have no choice but to fix the code. As @Daniel mentions, not every fault will cause a catchable exception. It just as likely may undetectably corrupt other parts of the MATLAB process' address space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which platform are you using?  There are methods to help *debug* your MEX files.  Whenever there is a segmentation fault, you can use an IDE to tell you where in the code it's crashing.

Here are the directions for Mac OS:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-on-mac-platforms.html

Here are the directions for Linux: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-on-linux-platforms.html

Here are the directions for Windows:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-on-microsoft-windows-platforms.html

**NB:**  I am *against* referring the OP to a link off-site to help with his or her question.  I usually include most of the answer in my posts and provide links as references.  Because you haven't told me what platform you're using, I will not write solutions for all platforms as that will take too much time.  As such (and I'm praying that the links are stable for a long time), you can refer to the appropriate link for your platform.