# error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mex.h': No such file or directory

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-2013

I've just installed Matlab 2014 and Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013. I've already setup mex compiler in my matlab, and tested it with a simple mex-file. But, when I want to debug a project in Visual Studio, and it reaches to debug a mex file, I get the following Error:

> Error 1 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mex.h': No such file or directory

Can anybody help me to get rid of this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you followed a tutorial on how to correctly debug Matlab files in VS?

Comment: This error is not specific to mex files; it means you did not configure the project correctly, so the preprocessor cannot find the header to include.

Comment: You need to make sure that you have configured VS properly so that it can debug MATLAB MEX files.  See my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714141/preventing-a-mex-file-from-crashing-in-matlab/23714301#23714301

Comment: Thanks Ray! Yes, it was for VS configuration.