# Error message while using VideoReader

Tags: matlab

I try to load a frame in `VideoReader`:

```
v=VideoReader('E:\001.mov');
im=read(v,1);
```

And then MATLAB gets stuck and shows the following error message:

[image: error message]

I assume this is not specific to the VideoReader, and might have to do with things that relate to memory etc.

These are the details:

```
MATLAB crash file:C:\Users\jonatron\AppData\Local\Temp\matlab_crash_dump.7376-1:


------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Access violation detected at Thu Aug 17 13:54:16 2017
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Default Encoding    : windows-1252
  Graphics card 1     : NVIDIA ( 0x10de ) NVIDIA GeForce 210  Version 9.18.13.4144
  Graphics card 2     : Intel Corporation ( 0x8086 ) Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 Version 9.18.10.3204
  Graphics card 3     : DemoForge ( 0x0 ) Mirage Driver Version 2.0.105.0
  Host Name           : WICCWEI-FLHB23J
  MATLAB Architecture : win64
  MATLAB Root         : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a
  MATLAB Version      : 8.5.0.197613 (R2015a)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise 
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Access violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 00000000fc621110  RBX = 0000000000000010
  RCX = 000000018801f920  RDX = 00000000fc61c570
  RSP = 000000018801f850  RBP = 00000000fc61e3b0
  RSI = 0000000000000f20  RDI = 0000000000000010

   R8 = 0000000000000010   R9 = 0000000000000f20
  R10 = 000000000000005f  R11 = 00000000ffffffff
  R12 = 0000000000000f20  R13 = 00000000ffffffff
  R14 = 00000000c9d75660  R15 = 0000000000000f00

  RIP = 00000000ee83b209  EFL = 00010202

   CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00000000ee83b209                     C:\Windows\system32\ffmpeg.dll+02667017 av_vc1_decode_frame+00282841
[  1] 0x00000000ee83b6f1                     C:\Windows\system32\ffmpeg.dll+02668273 av_vc1_decode_frame+00284097
[  2] 0x00000000ee83e94a                     C:\Windows\system32\ffmpeg.dll+02681162 av_vc1_decode_frame+00296986
[  3] 0x00000000ee6a4b1a                     C:\Windows\system32\ffmpeg.dll+01002266 FFIsSkipped+00444458
[  4] 0x00000000ee6e0a89                     C:\Windows\system32\ffmpeg.dll+01247881 FFIsSkipped+00690073
[  5] 0x00000000ee6e10a4                     C:\Windows\system32\ffmpeg.dll+01249444 FFIsSkipped+00691636
[  6] 0x00000000ee6e3f94                     C:\Windows\system32\ffmpeg.dll+01261460 FFIsSkipped+00703652
[  7] 0x00000000ee6e46b1                     C:\Windows\system32\ffmpeg.dll+01263281 FFIsSkipped+00705473
[  8] 0x00000000ee7a88db                     C:\Windows\system32\ffmpeg.dll+02066651 av_parser_close+00015275
[  9] 0x00000000ee7a75df                     C:\Windows\system32\ffmpeg.dll+02061791 av_parser_close+00010415
[ 10] 0x000007fefe1a415f                     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll+00016735 srand+00000147
[ 11] 0x000007fefe1a6ebd                     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll+00028349 ftime64_s+00000477
[ 12] 0x00000000774459cd                   C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll+00088525 BaseThreadInitThunk+00000013
[ 13] 0x000000007757a561                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00173409 RtlUserThreadStart+00000033


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.
```

I tried to uninstall/install MATLAB several times with versions 2014,2015,2017, but the message appears in all versions.

I use Windows 7, enterprise 64 bit.

Comment: It seems the answers to [this question on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360178/matlab-encountered-an-internal-error-and-needs-to-close) solve the problem.

Comment: Click on "Details" and post a screenshot of that. That might give more clues on what went wrong. Also do click "Send", you might receive feedback about available fixes.

Comment: @Navan, I've updated the question with the details

Comment: Which one of those two lines cause this problem? What is the size of your video file and RAM?  Do you see the same problem with the small size/other  video files or is it that particular file that causes the crash? If it is the second line that causes the problem,  try using the recommended command i.e. [`readFrame`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.readframe.html) instead

Comment: @SardarUsama, RAM is 16 GB, size of videofile is 3.97 GB. it happens also with videofiles of size 300 mb.

Comment: @SardarUsama, "Which of those lines cause the problem" - to which lines do u refer.

Comment: @SardarUsama, I've tried readFrame, it produces the same error.

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow strives to be professional knowledge database, so don't use text speak abbreviations as "msg". You don't gain anything (well, perhaps a whole second for the five times you wrote that), and it is harmful to the readability of the post. The same goes for your default signature at the end of the post ("cheers")

Comment: @jarhead Your code, that you've written in your post, has two lines. I was referring to that.

Comment: @SardarUsama, the 2nd line.

Comment: @SardarUsama, yes. when I read the frame it crashes.

Comment: Try upgrading your graphics drivers

Comment: @SardarUsama, they are up to date.

Comment: Well the only guess I have left is the codec issue.  As from your last post, you're using 4.0.1 version of the codecs. The latest version is  4.1.7. Try with the latest version

Comment: @SardarUsama, I've updated the codecs as u say, it does not help.

Comment: As suggested in the error message, you may create a Service Request at http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

Comment: This `ffmpeg.dll` is installed by Windows Codec Pack and is dated 2016/12/14. No further version info. This Dll is not even provided by ffmpeg.org. Seems to be a custom build for the Codec Pack. I suggest to de-install this package and try the latest K-Lite Codec Pack. It's just a few days old.

Comment: Convert the video to other format.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use another video with different format 
If it fails again, copy your Video into Drive C:\ and try again.